# MSP430 microcontroller - how to check addressing modes

Tags: c, simulation, microcontroller, msp430

I'm programming a MSP430 in C language as a simulation of real microcontroller. I got stuck in addressing modes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_CPU), especially:

- Addressing modes using R0 (PC)
- Addressing modes using R2 (SR) and R3 (CG), special-case decoding

  1. I don't understand what does mean 0(PC), 2(SR) and 3(CG). What they are?
  2. How to check these values?

Comment: Are you really programming in C, or are you using assembly?

Comment: see the answer in electrical engineering, or maybe I will repost it here.  you shouldnt as the same question in two places.

Comment: dont use external links in questions or answers or at least not as important portions of the question or answer since the remote link could eventually change and make this question useless to SO readers.  re-write or otherwise post the external information so that it is in/on stackoverflow in the question or answer.

Comment: @dwelch My hat is off to you for even understanding the intent of the original question.

Comment: not sure yet if I did understand which part the OP is confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so for the source if the as bits are 01 and the source register bits are a 0 which is the pc for reference then

ADDR Symbolic. Equivalent to x(PC). The operand is in memory at address PC+x.

if the ad bit is a 1 and the destination is a 0 then also

ADDR Symbolic. Equivalent to x(PC). The operand is in memory at address PC+x.

x is going to be another word that follows this instruction so the cpu will fetch the next word, add it to the pc and that is the source

if the as bits are 11 and the source is register 0, the source is an immediate value which is in the next word after the instruction.

if the as bits are 01 and the source is a 2 which happens to be the SR register for reference then the address is x the next word after the instruction (&ADDR)

if the ad bit is a 1 and the destination register is a 2 then it is also an &ADDR

if the as bits are 10 the source bits are a 2, then the source is the constant value 4 and we dont have to burn a word in flash after the instruction for that 4.

it doesnt make sense to have a destination be a constant 4 so that isnt a real combination.

repeat for the rest of the table.

you can have both of these addressing modes at the same time

```
mov #0x5A80,&0x0120
```

generates

```
c000:   b2 40 80 5a     mov #23168, &0x0120 ;#0x5a80
c004:   20 01
```

which is

```
0x40b2 0x5a80 0x0120

0100000010110010
0100 opcode mov
0000 source
1 ad
0 b/w
11 as
0010 destination
```

so we have an as of 11 with source of 0 the immediate #x, an ad of 1 with a destination 2 so the destination is &ADDR.  this is an important experiment because when you have 2 x values, a three word instruction basically which one goes with the source and which the destination

```
0x40b2 0x5a80 0x0120
```

so the address 0x5a80 which is the destination is the first x to follow the instruction then the source 0x0120 an immediate comes after that.

if it were just an immediate and a register then

```
c006:   31 40 ff 03     mov #1023,  r1  ;#0x03ff

0x4031 0x03FF

0100000000110001
0100 mov
0000 source
0 ad
0 b/w
11 as
0001 dest
```

as of 11 and source of 0 is #immediate the X is 0x03FF in this case the word that follows.  the destination is ad of 0

```
Register direct. The operand is the contents of Rn
```

where destination in this case is r1

so the first group Rn, x(Rn), @Rn and @Rn+ are the normal cases, the ones below that that you are asking about are special cases, if you get a combination that fits into a special case then you do that otherwise you do the normal case like the mov immediate to r1 example above.  the destination of r1 was a normal Rn case.

Comment: use the gnu tools.  (apt-get install gcc-msp430 msp430-libc) you can assemble then disassemble easily, the syntax might not exactly match the wikipedia page but you can figure it out (compile some very simple C programs and compile to asm or disassemble those to get clues on the syntax).  then start trying various addressing modes in asm then asseble and disassemble with the toolchain then you can disassemble or simulate with your program.

Comment: If you are not able do all of these things (craft asm code to generate the various instruction possibilities) then you are not remotely ready to write a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

- As=01, Ad=1, R0 (**ADDR**): This is exactly the same as **x(Rn)**, i.e., the operand is in memory at address R0+x.

  This is used for data that is stored near the code that uses it, when the compiler does not know at which absolute address the code will be located, but it knows that the data is, e.g., twenty words behind the instruction.
- As=11, R0 (**#x**): This is exactly the same as **@R0+**, and is used for instructions that need a word of data from the instruction stream. For example, this assembler instruction:

  ```
  MOV #1234, R5
  ```

  is actually encoded and implemented as:

  ```
  MOV @PC+, R5
  .dw 1234
  ```

  After the CPU has read the MOV instruction word, PC points to the data word. When reading the first MOV operand, the CPU reads the data word, and increments PC again.
- As=01, Ad=1, R2 (**&ADDR**): this is exactly the same as x(Rn), but the R2 register reads as zero, so what you end up with is the value of x.

  Using the always-zero register allows to encode absolute addresses without needing a special addressing mode for this (just a special register).
- constants -1/0/1/2/4/8: it would not make sense to use the SR and CG registers with most addressing modes, so these encodings are used to generate special values without a separate data word, to save space:

  ```
  encoding:       what actually happens:
  MOV @SR, R5     MOV #4, R5
  MOV @SR+, R5    MOV #8, R5
  MOV CG, R5      MOV #0, R5
  MOV x(CG), R5   MOV #1, R5  (no word for x)
  MOV @CG, R5     MOV #2, R5
  MOV @CG+, R5    MOV #-1, R5
  ```